# Using devise methods from Ember

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js, devise

I have an ember controller with several actions. I need to add a method that uses devise's send_reset_password_instructions to take an email and send the password reset instructions to it. I am unclear how to access devise's ruby methods from the Ember side of the project.

Comment: The only way for ember to invoke anything in your rails app is via HTTP. So you would need to use ajax to send the request. The default route in Devise is `POST /resource/password`. Usually this means `POST /user/password`.

Comment: You can look at the form at `/resource/password/new` to figure out the params.